# Flutter/Firebase application stream builder load data

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing mobile application with Flutter.

In my application, I made real time messaging.

By getting more users, there are many chats in chat room.

I am just wondering how to get data, whenever I scroll up rather then all data in initial state.

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: controller.stream,
  builder: (context, snapshots) {
    if (!snapshots.hasData) {
      return Container();
    } else {
      List<MessageBox> messages = [];
      snapshots.data.docs.forEach((msg) {
        ChatMessage message = ChatMessage.fromDocument(msg);
        if (messages.length != 0) {
          DateTime preTime =
              messages[messages.length - 1].chatMessage.time;
          DateTime thisTime = message.time;
          if (preTime.year != thisTime.year ||
              preTime.month != thisTime.month ||
              preTime.day != thisTime.day) {
            messages.add(MessageBox(
              curreuntUserID: authentication.currentUser.userID,
              isCurrentUserMessage:
                  authentication.currentUser.userID ==
                      ChatMessage.fromDocument(msg).senderID,
              chatMessage: ChatMessage(
                  tagedUserIDList: null,
                  time: preTime,
                  messageID: null,
                  message: null,
                  messageType: null,
                  recieverID: null,
                  senderID: null,
                  imageURLs: null),
            ));
          }
        }
        messages.add(MessageBox(
          curreuntUserID: authentication.currentUser.userID,
          chatMessage: message,
          isCurrentUserMessage: authentication.currentUser.userID ==
              ChatMessage.fromDocument(msg).senderID,
        ));
      });
      return MediaQuery.removePadding(
        context: context,
        removeBottom: true,
        child: ListView(
          reverse: true,
          children: messages,
        ),
      );
    }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to [paginate data from Firestore with queries and cursors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data to *only* load in when you scroll, use a ListView.builder. This only renders the text on screen and slightly above/below.